# Retornar data de hoje em C# em formato específico

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Minha saída tem que ser `"2015-02-01"`

Tentei por `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-m-d")`, mas ela não poem os 0 entre os dias e os meses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se quer dois dígitos, precisa especificar dois dígitos:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Atenção com as maiúsculas. `m` é minuto, `M` é mês.

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/B39bZp)**.

Não está na pergunta, mas tem duas coisas importantes que podem ser úteis:

- além do `Now`, existe o `UtcNow`.
- para converter UTC para tempo local, você tem o `ToLocalTime()`. Pode usar vinculado a um TimeZone específico, se preferir.

Seguem os campos mais comuns:

```
   d   dia do mês,  1-31
  dd   dia do mês, 01-31
 ddd   dia da semana ( Dom, Seg ... )
dddd   dia da semana ( Domingo ... )
   h   hora  1-12
  hh   hora 01-12
   H   hora  0-23
  HH   hora 00-23
   m   minuto  0-59
  mm   minuto 00-59
   M   mês     1-12
  MM   mês    01-12
 MMM   mês (Jan, Fev ... )
MMMM   mês (Janeiro ... )
   s   segundo  0-59
  ss   segundo 00-59
   t   A/P 
  tt   AM/PM
   y   ano     0-99
  yy   ano    00-00
 yyy   ano   000-999
yyyy   ano  0000-9999
   :   separador de tempo
   /   separador de data
"string" / 'string' valor literal
```

Documentação oficial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Já existe resposta que atende ao solicitado, mas há um padrão que pode ser mais adequado, dependendo do que se está fazendo. Claro que a necessidade específica pode ser usar um formato definido pelo programador ali mesmo, mas na maioria dos casos o melhor é é usar uma padrão conhecido ao invés de "inventar" um padrão. Então na maior parte dos casos o código mais correto pra isto é usar a cultura.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("pt-BR", false).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/i4daaT). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NCkENc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Culture/DateTimeFormat.cs).

Dei uma opção usando a cultura corrente que deve ser a mais adequada na maioria dos casos, afinal é comum a aplicação deixar as configurações gerais do usuário determinar isto e não o que o programador quer que o usuário veja. Note que o dotNetFiddle usa o padrão americano por padrão, por isso fica fora do esperado. Fiz também com cultura invariante. O assunto é extenso e não cabe aqui.

Obviamente é possível usar outras culturas, incluindo uma que usar o padrão ano-mês-dia, por exemplo: ko, pl, sv, lt, mn, km, si, ko-KR, pl-PL, sv-SE, lt-LT, mn-MN, km-KH, si-LK, se-SE, fr-CA, en-CA, smj-SE, en-ZA, sma-SE, sma, mn-Cyrl, smj.